Why did Blade's throwing glaive disintegrate Azazel in "Deadpool & Wolverine"?
In the 2024 MCU film Deadpool & Wolverine, during the fight scene at Cassandra Nova’s base, Blade throws his glaive (boomerang-like weapon) at Azazel. Surprisingly, this causes Azazel to disintegrate into dust or ash, much like the vampires in the Blade film series when struck by Blade’s weapons, which I believe are infused with silver, a substance lethal to vampires.
What’s puzzling is that this disintegration effect seems unique to Azazel—I didn't see it happen when Blade uses his weapons (glaive, sword, or gun) on other characters in Deadpool & Wolverine.


Azazel disintegrates after being struck by Blade
It's worth noting that this disintegration is different from Azazel's teleportation or "bamfing" ability, which looks like this:

Now, compare this to how vampires disintegrate in the original Blade film:

Vampires disintegrating after being struck by Blade in the original 1998 Blade film 



According to the Wikipedia article for Azazel, he's a mutant with a demonic appearance. There's no mention of him being a vampire, which makes his disintegration puzzling.
I'm wondering if Blade's weapons—glaive or sword—have some special property, perhaps explained in the comics, that allows them to disintegrate other demon-type or monster-like characters, not just vampires. Alternatively, is there something unique about Azazel that makes him vulnerable to Blade's weapons?

Bit of a stretch, but maybe Blade's sword has the same effect on Neyaphem that it does on vampires?

Are you sure he's not bamfing?

I don't think it has much to do with the sword, since it doesn't have that effect on vampires when it inflicts non-lethal wounds on them, such as cutting off Peter Quinn's hand in the first film. Quinn also doesn't disintegrate when Blade stakes him through the shoulder. He does disintegrate, however, when Blade cuts his head off with razor wire. I think the idea is that vampires in the Blade universe automatically burn up/disintegrate when they sustain lethal wounds, like they do in Buffy the Vampire Slayer.

@Darren It doesn't look like his bamf animation. (I'll add a screenshot to my post.)

@LogicDictates My bad. Blade uses his glaive (boomerang-like weapon) in that scene, not his sword. I had assumed that the silver content in his weapons was what caused vampires to disintegrate on contact.

Whistler says vampires are "severely allergic" to silver in Blade (1998) and the screenplay indicates that several of Blade's weapons are made of or tipped with silver. That said, these vampires burn up after Blade inflicts lethal wounds on them in hand-to-hand combat in that film, so it seems to be an inherent trait of their physiology that they don't leave intact corpses, regardless of how they're killed.

@LogicDictates I see. Perhaps Azazel has a similar physiology to vampires, causing him to disintegrate upon death rather than being a specific effect of Blade's weapon.
